# JXMapKit help with map formatting

Tags: java, swing, formatting, maps

I have made a desktop java application that uses JXMapKit to incorporate maps. My problem is that the size of the map is too small and i don' t know how to format it. I checked the JXMapKit class methods here: http://swinglabs.org/hudson/job/SwingX-WS%20Continuous%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXMapKit.html but i could not find something relevant. Any help? cause i feel i am goin about it completely wrong.

edit. i have tried mapView.setSize(400,400); but it's not working.

Comment: We can provide more help if you provide the code for your GUI where the map is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JXMapKit will take up as much space as the LayoutManager in which it's located allows.  As a sample test do something like the following

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       JXMapKit kit = new JXMapKit();
       JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
       parentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       parentPanel.add(kit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setContentPane(parentPanel);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

The CENTER borderlayout piece should make it take up as much space as possible.